# Toggle material design icons

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
    $.fn.extend({
    treed: function (o) {
      
      var openedClass = 'glyphicon-minus-sign';
      var closedClass = 'glyphicon-plus-sign';

       var openedIconClass = 'keyboard_arrow_down';
      var closedIconClass = 'keyboard_arrow_up';
      
      if (typeof o != 'undefined'){
        if (typeof o.openedClass != 'undefined'){
        openedClass = o.openedClass;
        }
        if (typeof o.closedClass != 'undefined'){
        closedClass = o.closedClass;
        }
      };
      
        //initialize each of the top levels
        var tree = $(this);
        tree.addClass("tree");
        tree.find('li').has("ul").each(function () {
            $('.material-icons').css('display', 'block');
            var branch = $(this); //li with children ul
            branch.prepend("<i class='indicator glyphicon " + closedClass + "'></i>");
            branch.addClass('branch');
  
            branch.on('click', function (e) {

                   $('.material-icons').toggleClass("display-block");
                    $(this).toggleClass("orange-light");
                if($(this).hasClass("orange-light")){
                     $(".arrow", this).text('keyboard_arrow_up');
                }
                if (this == e.target) {

                    var icon = $(this).children('i:first');
                    console.log(icon.text);
                    icon.toggleClass(openedClass + " " + closedClass);
                      icon.toggleClass(openedIconClass + " " + closedIconClass);
                    $(this).children().children().toggle();

                }
            })
            branch.children().children().toggle();
        });
        //fire event from the dynamically added icon
      tree.find('.branch .indicator').each(function(){
        $(this).on('click', function () {
            $(this).closest('li').click();
        });
      });
        //fire event to open branch if the li contains an anchor instead of text
        tree.find('.branch>a').each(function () {
            $(this).on('click', function (e) {
                $(this).closest('li').click();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
        //fire event to open branch if the li contains a button instead of text
        tree.find('.branch>button').each(function () {
            $(this).on('click', function (e) {
                $(this).closest('li').click();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    }
});

//Initialization of treeviews

$('#tree1').treed();

$('#tree2').treed({openedClass:'glyphicon-folder-open', closedClass:'glyphicon-folder-close'});

$('#tree3').treed({openedClass:'glyphicon-chevron-right', closedClass:'glyphicon-chevron-down'});
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


    <style type="text/css">
    .tree, .tree ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none
}
.tree ul {
    margin-left:1em;
    position:relative
}
.tree ul ul {
    margin-left:.5em
}

.tree ul:before {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    width:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:18px;
    bottom:16px;
    left:40px;
    border-left:1px solid;
    border-color: #556f7b;
}
.tree li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0 1em;
    line-height:2em;
  
    position:relative;
    font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: left;
  color: #000000;
}
.tree ul li:before {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    width:10px;
    height:0;
    border-top:1px solid;
    margin-top:-1px;
    position:absolute;
    top:32px;
    left:40px;
  border-color: #556f7b;
}
.tree ul li:last-child:before {
    background:#fff;
    height:auto;
    top:32px;
    bottom:0
}

.indicator {
    margin-right:5px;
}
.tree li a {
    text-decoration: none;
   font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: left;
  color: #000000;
}
.tree li button, .tree li button:active, .tree li button:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#369;
    border:none;
    background:transparent;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    outline: 0;
  
}

.branch{
      
  height: 64px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border: solid 1px transparent;
      padding-top: 18px!important;
      cursor: pointer;
}
.indicator{
    color: transparent;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.first-level .branch{
    padding-left: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}
 .orange-light{
    background: #fff4e7;
 }
 .display-block{
    display:block!important;
 }
</style>
    <body id="admin-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2" id="sidebar-content"> 
              
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-10" id="main-content">
                   <ul id="tree2">
                <li><a href="#">Level 

 <i class="material-icons arrow" style="float: right; padding-left: 24px; padding-right: 8px; color: #556f7b;  display: block!important;">
keyboard_arrow_down
</i>

</a>
<a href="">
<i class="material-icons" style="float: right;     padding-left: 28px;color: #f8971c; display: block!important; padding-right: 28px;
    border-right: 1px solid #e8e8e8;">
send
</i>
</a>
<a href="">
 <i class="material-icons" style="float: right; color: #556f7b;     padding-right: 28px;
    border-right: 1px solid #e8e8e8;  display: block!important;">
list
</i>
</a>


            
    
                    <ul class="first-level" style="    margin-top: 22px; margin-left: -15px; margin-right: -15px;">
                       <li>faef 
                            <ul>
                                <li>Reports
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Report1</li>
                                        <li>Report2</li>
                                        <li>Report3</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                             
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>afasf
                            <ul>
                                <li>Reports
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Report1</li>
                                        <li>Report2</li>
                                        <li>Report3</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                             
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                       
                    </ul>
             
                   
                    
             
                   </li>
           
            </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have this code here and the part of arrow material design icon I managed on click to make arrow up, but then when I click again the card the icon doesnt toggle. can someone help me with this please..? how can I toggle material design  icons is there a way, if so can you help me here I am new on coding and i am trying everything here but it just wont work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, all you need is to change the element text to change the material design icon. You can change it freely and it works every time.

Seems like your code needs to be split into smaller functions for you to find out where is you error.

```js
$(window).on('click', function(event) {
  var icon = $('.arrow');
  icon.toggleClass('up');
  if ( icon.hasClass('up') ) {
    icon.text('keyboard_arrow_down');
  } else {
    icon.text('keyboard_arrow_up');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<i class="material-icons arrow up">keyboard_arrow_down
</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<i id="toggleId" class="material-icons" onclick="toggleMaker()">keyboard_arrow_down</i>

<script>
  function toggleMaker() {
    var toggleElement = document.getElementById("toggleId")
    if(toggleElement.innerHTML === "keyboard_arrow_down") {
      toggleElement.innerHTML = "keyboard_arrow_up";
    }
    else {
      toggleElement.innerHTML = "keyboard_arrow_down";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: pode ser feito sem jquery.